# When does almost sure pointwise convergnce of a sequence of stochastic processes imply uniform almost sure convergence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, empirical-processes

Suppose  $\{X_n(t) \; : \; t \in K\}$ $n=1,2,...$ is a sequence of stochastic processes indexed by a compact subset of a metric space $K$, and $\{X_\infty(t) \; : \; t\in K\}$ is a limiting process satisfying $X_n(t) \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} X_\infty(t)$ for all $t \in K$. My question is: under what conditions is this enough to imply that $\sup_{t \in K} |X_n(t) -X_\infty(t) | \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$? I assume this must depend on the continuity of each process, and perhaps on the complexity of $K$, but I cannot find a suitable general result of this type.

Comment: The [Arzelà-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzelà–Ascoli_theorem) gives a sufficient condition: it is enough to assume that a.s. the family $(X_n)$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Comment: Actually this condition is also necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michh! Must it be the case that each $X_n$ is (equi)continuous though? For example if $X_n$ is the uniform empirical process (the emprical CDF based on $n$ iid uniform[0,1] random variables) then it is not continuous for any $n$, but the conclusion is the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem. I assumed then that perhaps there would be something more general than Arzela-Ascoli that might apply in these settings.

Comment: My bad, I assumed your $X_n$ are continuous. In the case of empirical processes, $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ and the $X_n$ are cadlag (right-continuous with left limits). So what you need is an analogue of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem in the space of cadlag functions endowed with the Skorokhod topology. See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45632) and also the book it references: Section 12 of Billingsley's Convergence of probability measures. Not sure what to say if $K$ is an arbitrary compact set though.